# Video file upload(.mp4) to server using rest api in react

Tags: reactjs, rest

I have a button called 'upload' to upload a .mp4 video file to browser. On clicking the submit button, video file should be saved to the server. To achieve this, I have to use rest api.

```
import React from 'react';

export class Upload extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        selectedFile: null
    };

    this.onChangeHandler = this.onChangeHandler.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}
onChangeHandler = event => {

    this.setState({
        selectedFile: event.target.files[0],
        loaded: 0,
    })
    console.log(event.target.files[0])

}

handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    fetch('**path**', {
        method: 'POST',
 ** Don't know how to send video file(.mp4) to server  **

}

render() {
    return (
        < div >

            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <label>
                    Upload a file:
                    <br /><br />
                    <input type="file" name="file" onChange={this.onChangeHandler} />
                </label><br /><br />
                <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
            </form >

        </div >
    );
}
}
```

Please someone help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is how I think it should go

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Upload extends React.Component<any, any> {
    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            selectedFile: null
        };
    }
    onChangeHandler = (event: any) => {
        this.setState({
            selectedFile: event.target.files[0],
            loaded: 0,
        });
        console.log(event.target.files[0]);
    };

    handleSubmit = (event: any) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const formData = new FormData();
        const { selectedFile } = this.state;
        formData.append('inputFile', selectedFile);
        fetch('/api/upload', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData,
        });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            < div >
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <label>
                        Upload a file: <br /><br />
                        <input type="file" name="file" onChange={this.onChangeHandler} />
                    </label>
                    <br /><br />
                    <button type="submit">
                        Upload
                    </button>
                </form >
            </div >
        );
    }
}
```

and with that being said, the backend api can expect the file in files directory .

express example

```
import express from 'express';

const fileupload = require("express-fileupload");
app.use(fileupload());
```

```
app.post('/api/upload', (req: any, res) => {
    console.log(req.files);
    // handle the file here
    res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For uploading some files, you've the package "react-firebase-file-uploader". With that, you can upload some files easily with Firebase.

The package : https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-firebase-file-uploader
A random tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dVh5kvDMPNY

Comment: This does not concern the OP :)